# Why is there padding in table?

Tags: html, html-table, padding

I am making a table and although I did not add any padding, some of the th in table 1 (see fiddle) seem to have a small padding-top. How can I fix that?

http://jsfiddle.net/6a1usq1s/

```
 <table id="table1">
<tr>
    <th>
        <div class="body-table">VersF)</div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="h2-table">Drse</div>
        <div class="body-table subheading">son</div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="h2-table">sne</div>
        <div class="body-table subheading">Sstz</div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="h2-table">Br</div>
        <div class="body-table subheading">s</div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="h2-table">a</div>
        <div class="body-table subheading">an</div>
    </th>
    <th>
        <div class="h2-table">a</div>
        <div class="body-table subheading">a</div>
    </th>
</tr>
```

Comment: That's the default style.

Comment: If you are talking about that display that lowercase letters is lower than uppercase letters (from top) than it's nature of line height and letters. Check vertical-align: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_vertical-align&preval=baseline

Comment: doesn't work :(
and in my case the first letters are all uppercase, just not in the example ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
vertical-align:top;
```

was the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to nullify paddings for tr or td to cancel use of the styles installed in the browser by default:

```
padding: 0;
```

Then you can set height for div or tr/td, and to use line-height property for regulation of provision of the text in a cell (if the text is located in one line). If height is equal to line-height the text will settle down vertically in the middle.

```
height: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
```

Experiment with this property.